# What type of prime is $3^p - 2^p$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: number-theory

What is the name given to primes of the form:

$$3^p - 2^p,$$ where $p$ is prime itself. I did searches along the number line for $3^p - 2^p$ for any positive integer $p,$ from $1$ to $10000$ and found that the only instances that yielded prime numbers are when $p$ is prime itself.

For example $3^{17} - 2^{17} = 129 009091$ and this number is a prime number.

The full list for p under $10000$ is:
$$2\\
3\\
5\\
17\\
29 \\
31 \\
53 \\
59 \\
101 \\
277 \\
647 \\
1061 \\
2381 \\
2833 \\
3613 \\
3853 \\
3929 \\
5297 \\
7417
$$

All of these $19$ numbers are primes numbers and computing $3^p - 2^p$ for any of them as $p$ yields a prime number.

I know what Mersenne primes are. They are primes of the form $2^p - 1,$ where $p$ is prime.

If you know the name of $3^p - 2^p$ primes, when $p$ is itself prime then teach it to me and tell me about its known properties. For now I conjecture there may be some kind of symmetry between these and the well documented Mersenne primes.

Comment: I don't suppose these things have names.  Usually, the families of primes that get special attention either arise in other contexts (as the Mersenne primes appear  in the study of perfect numbers) or they are especially easy to test for primality (again, Mersenne).

Comment: Worth remarking: $x^n-y^n$ is divisible by $x-y$ so it's easy to see that your numbers are not prime if the exponent is not prime.

Comment: If $d$ is a divisor of $p,$ then $3^d-2^d$ is a divisor of $3^p-2^p.$ That is why you get no composite cases.

Comment: @lulu - that doesn't apply here because $3-2 = 1$.  ThomasAndrews has it right.

Comment: It applies when $p$ is not prime, @MichaelLugo

Comment: My point was that, if your exponent is $n\times m$, then your expression is divisible by $3^n-2^n$.  Granted, that is not interesting if $n$ or $m$ is $1$ but it is interesting if $n,m>1$.

Comment: If $d$ is a divisor of $p$ then let $n=p/d.$ Then $3^p-2^p=(3^d)^n-(2^d)^n$ so  is divisible by $3^d-2^d.$ @MichaelLugo

Comment: [Such primes](https://oeis.org/A001047) are [well-studied](https://oeis.org/A057468), but don't seem to be named.

Comment: @J.G. I'm not convinced that a sequence having an OEIS page qualifies it as "well-studied".

Comment: @Nate Somewhat, then, on the strength of the primary literature both pages cite.

Answer (score 0):

These types of primes are not prominent enough to be given a separate name but you can see a list of them [here](https://oeis.org/A001047) if you are interested and [here](https://oeis.org/A057468) for their generators.

Comment: Those links were given in a comment, two years ago.

Comment: That's correct.